# Ansible console output and log levels

Tags: logging, ansible

I have created a role to deploy stack. Where I am taking care of role back also (If stack is failed, roll back up to certain tasks). However While everything is going smooth, on the console rollback tasks are displayed as `skipped` tasks (in non verbose mode also).

```
TASK: [deploy-stack | Deleting_Validation_Template] ***************************
skipping: [10.17.10.150]

TASK: [deploy-stack | shell echo 'Template Validation has Failed'] ************
skipping: [10.17.10.150]

TASK: [deploy-stack | Deploying_the_Stack..] **********************************
changed: [10.17.10.150]
```

1) Is it possible to hide `skipped` tasks from the console?

2) I have noticed, if I am not running playbook in super verbose mode (ansible-playbook stack.yml -vvvv), ansible log file is not populating the detailed information (basically what we see in console, is going into the ansible log file `/var/log/ansible.log`). Is it possible to define log level to push more information in to log file, while running playbook in non verbose mode (ansible-playbook stack.yml) ?

Comment: that option might help youto solve the problem: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#display-skipped-hosts

Answer (score 2):

1) As stated in the comment above you can turn off printing *statuses* of skipped tasks, but not the names of them – parameter [display_skipped_hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#display-skipped-hosts)
If you want to customize the output further, you need some code and make you own *stdout* plugin for Ansible:

- Take the [default.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py) callback plugin, modify it to your needs and place to callback_plugins subdirectory of your playbook (or Ansible global plugins dir)
- Set [stdout_callback](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#stdout-callback) parameter to point to your custom plugin
- Note that the the templated task name is not available inside `v2_runner_on_*` methods, so if you don't want to print skipped tasks' names you need to capture the name into global dict inside `v2_playbook_on_task_start` but not print them out in this method, and then later print or not print it inside `v2_runner_on_*` methods (see use of `self.stats` and `task._uuid` in [profile_tasks.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.py) for reference)

2) There is no easy solution to this, because default logger shares the same method that is used to print info to console.
But if you do you own custom stdout plugin, you can print verbose info supplying `log_only=True` to `self._display.display` method (see `v2_playbook_on_stats` in default.py callback for example).
Alternatively you can make another callback plugin used just for logging.

Comment: im struggling with a similar thing, im using log_plays.py (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/37470) to have each host log into his own logfile, but don't see the tasknames in the output. i'll look into your profile_tasks hint..but it seems daunting..